# Изменение размера Label под текст

Tags: xcode, swift

В сториборде есть label, в который подставляется текст различной длины.

```
@IBOutlet weak var textLabel: UILabel!

textLabel.numberOfLines = 0
textLabel.text = "длинный текст"
textLabel.sizeToFit()
```

Проблема в том, что этот текст обрезается, если он длинный. Как этого избежать?

`textLabel.sizeToFit()` не помогает.

Comment: а sizeToFit() собственно вызывается КАЖДЫЙ раз после того как новый текст установлен? или только один раз в самом начале?

Comment: каждый раз при смене

Answer (score 1):

Передо мной стояла аналогичная задача. Привожу код, который работает в моем приложении:

```
textLabel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.ByWordWrapping
textLabel.numberOfLines = 0
textLabel.text = "длинный текст"
```

Answer (score 0):

Следует добавить строку для обновления новых размеров

```
textLabel.setNeedsDisplay()
```

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение?